# Django Rest framework conditional delete

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[SOLVED]

I just solved like this

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        password = request.data.get('password')
        article_id = request.data.get('article')
        instance = self.get_object()
        if password == instance.password:
            self.perform_destroy(instance)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

And request with password parameter, it was deleted successfully.

---

[delete.py]

```
import requests

r = requests.delete("http://mysite/article/45/")
```

[views.py]

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def delete(self, pk, request):
        method = self.request.method
        article = article.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if method == 'DELETE':
            if request.password == article.password:
                article.delete()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

---

I want to add some condition when DELETE data.

Here is my models.py and serializers.py

[serializers.py]

```
class articleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userkey = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = article
        fields = ('articleNo', 'content', 'date', 'userkey', 'password')
```

[models.py]

```
class article(models.Model):
    articleNo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userkey = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='1234')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

For example, below data is in database.

```
| articleNo | content           | date                       | userkey |password|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        33 | test article      | 2018-03-11 05:00:15.428661 | a1b2c3d4 | 1234  |
```

When "DELETE" method request, I want to compare request's password and article's password. If it is same, data will be deleted.

Refer to document, I think I have to override `def delete()`.

But I don't know exactly what should I do.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Add your VIEW code as well.

Comment: what view are you using? ModelViewset? APIView?

Comment: can you add your `views.py` as well please?

Comment: I added my views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a delete payload as below,

```
request_payload = {
    "password": "request's password",
    "article": some_integer_value_article_instance,
    # other data
}
```

and your views be like

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def delete(self, pk, request):
        password = request.data.get('password')
        article_id = request.data.get('article')
        article_instance = article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        if password == article_instance.password:
            article_instance.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

Comment: I modified views.py as your comment, and construct payload like you. But when I request payload except password, It deleted well. All I want is request.password == article.password, then deleted article. I added python request on my post

Comment: What you mean by `request.password` ? I couldn't understand

Comment: request.password is Request by user(HTTP Request) and article.password is password that stored in database. So, Requested password and stored password is same, article will be deleted. That is my scenario.

Comment: So, whats the output/error you have got after applying my answer ?

Comment: There is no error. Just deleted. (without password parameter, only article number parameter)

Comment: I Think,  you are missing something in your `delete.py`.... Try this  `request.delete(url,payload)`

Comment: Also, change `delete()` to `destroy()`

Comment: After change `delete()` to `destroy()` and insert parameter `params = {'password':'123', 'article':'46'}` to requests, it throws error like this -> `destroy() got multiple values for argument 'pk'`

Comment: I couldn't understand what happens to your code :(  I demonstrated one small [DRF project here](https://bitbucket.org/jerinpetergeorge/django_1_11). I think it would helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I just solved like this

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        password = request.data.get('password')
        article_id = request.data.get('article')
        instance = self.get_object()
        if password == instance.password:
            self.perform_destroy(instance)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

And request with password parameter, it was deleted successfully.

Answer (score -1):

In your views.py file you can put up a condition which acts if the method is delete.

```
if request.method == 'DELETE':
    #your code here
```